# Software Recommendations is online

Tags: discussion, stackexchange

[Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) is now in Public Beta. Maybe you could start answering some the [Android](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android) questions.

And, of course, we can let people know that such a site exists. (Migrating questions there is not really an option, however.)

I hope it does well.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, Al! dotVezz and me already joined in, pushing the site with answers to make good speed through its Beta phase :) Looks promising.

Comment: While its in Private Beta don't think anyone new (like me) can sign up if they didn't commit beforehand? At least I can't find a way to log in.

Comment: @GAThrawn: That's true, but the private beta only lasts a week.

Comment: You can actually get in by visiting the Area51 page and following the link there to the site, @GAThrawn.

Comment: Thanks @Shog9 had no idea that there was anything magic about Area51's visit site link compared to just visiting the site.

Comment: @AlE. Where is the link to Software Recommendations SE or is it not available as it is in closed beta ?

Comment: @Simon: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ is the URL. It's still in closed beta, so for now you will need to access it via [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/60887/software-recommendations) as Shog9 mentioned above.

Comment: @AlE. Thanks I'll just wait :)

Answer (score 4):

[Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) is now in public beta.

The site isn't taking migrations for the time being. The site needs to be able to grow at its own pace without suddenly having questions shoved at it from other sites. SR.SE moderators will let you know when the site starts accepting migrations.

Whenever you refer people to SR.SE, please always link to its quality guidelines.

- For [questions](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information), the most important point is that a recommendation must **both** define a **goal** or task to accomplish, and list some objective **requirements**.
- For [answers](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356/what-is-required-for-an-answer-to-be-high-quality), note that we want answers that **explain** how the requirements are met and how to accomplish the stated task — answers that merely mention an app and its description are likely to be summarily deleted.