# Should softwarerecs.stackexchange.com be added as a redirect site?

Tags: discussion, migration

Many questions come to this site for recommendations for Android applications that matches a specified need. Usually these questions for recommendations are closed as "too localized" because they meet the requirements of a single person rather than the Android community at large. There is, however, a software recommendation site on the Stack Exchange network: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com. This site is not listed on the page that allows questions to be recommended to other Stack Exchange sites. Can this link be added so these questions are not summarily closed as "too localized", yielding an alternate direction to satisfy the needs of the member?

Comment: ["We are not a dumping ground"](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/561/226). ["A vast majority of the recommendation questions asked on other Stack Exchange sites are crap and we don't want them."](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/762/226) ["I would reject any flag requesting migration to Software Recs (or any other beta site)."](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/658/226) Summary: while we are in beta, no. Afterwards, maybe.

Comment: "Too Localized" has not been a close reason for months.

Comment: **[Software Recommendations is now available as a destination](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2659/96277)**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Questions which would be closed as "too localized" (back when that was a closure reason) are not necessarily a good fit for *any* other SE site (though there might be exceptions).

But there's the "off-topic *Is there an app for X*", which much better fits your idea of an additional migration target. I share this with you: eventually, we should add this. But I also see Briam's concern (see his comment on the question itself): While a site is in Beta, it's not an official migration target. Though again, there are exceptions – and mods *can* migrate some questions manually, but will not do so regularly :)

#### TL;DR

- A Beta-site is no official migration target. So currently: NO.
- When SR leaves Beta: I'd say we should add it as migration target for the *Is there an app for X* questions.
- **UPDATE:** Now that it left Beta, take a look at [What's our stance on being a migration target?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2307/185) (related discussion at Meta.SR). As I already indicated, I see good chances having SR added as migration target. As with other targets: Only vote to migrate there if you're active on the other end (and know it is acceptable). Otherwise, rather vote to close as off-topic, as you would now.

Answer (score 2):

No question has been closed as "too localized" since the close reasons were changed some time ago.

Specialized needs aren't a problem: if there's a question about a very specific problem that needs to be solved, and the answer might or might not involve an app, that's fine, and it should be left open. It'll only be closed when certain reviewers only see "is there an app that can do this?" and stop reading the question. IMO, "is there an app" shouldn't be a magic word, and if there's a genuine problem to be solved, and the question is clear, it deserves an answer whatever form of words the questioner used.

The questions we want to discourage on this site are "there are 100 email apps; which ones have this particular feature?" because there'll be a list of answers and it'll never be complete or accurate because apps add and remove features all the time. As I understand it, these questions aren't really in softwarerecs's remit either.

Similarly, even vaguer questions like, "Which X app should I use?" are obviously opinion-based. I don't even use our custom app-recommendations close reason for these questions: close as opinion-based to make it clear why the question is unsuitable.

Answer (score 0):

I would say **no**.

For one thing, as a general rule Stack Exchange does not add beta sites as migration targets.

Second, Software Recs has some very *stringent* guidelines as to what is on-topic there. I believe that adding it as a migration target will result in the vast majority of migrated questions being rejected by Software Recs and, not too long after that, them asking for it to be removed from our migration paths.

See also [this answer from Gilles which details *how* they'd like to get referrals](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1705) from us.

I'll quote part of it here:

> For [questions](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information), the most important point is that a recommendation must both define a goal or task to accomplish, and list some objective requirements.

Migration is supposed to be for very good questions that just happen to be off-topic for their current site but would be a welcome addition on some other site within Stack Exchange. We should not migrate questions that will get downvotes and possibly closed on the target. The vast, vast majority of recommendation request questions here would not be welcome there.