# Can we add Software Recommendations SE as a destination for when an off-topic question needs migration?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, migration

When flagging a question as off-topic, Software Recommendations SE is not currently listed.  Can we get it added?

For those that don't know, Software Recommendations StackExchange is here:
https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Comment: I think a CM has to be asked for this. We mods don't have an option to add a migration site ourselves (I don't see one). As for the request, we do receive a good share of questions asking for app recommendation (not on a daily basis though) and it would make it easy for flag raisers / close voters to flag/vote for migration there.

Comment: @Firelord Do you think the request would be best received if it came from a mod?  If so, can you or one of the other mods do it if you are all in agreement and the community doesn't object?

Comment: While I can confirm we receive a good share of app questions, only few of them are suited for migration. Most would require severe rephrasing to fit site rules at SR, see [Where to ask for app recommendations?](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2060/16575) Being a mod on both sites, I might have to reject migrations from the other end then ;) But as the same can be said for any other "migration targets", please don't count that as objection. Need to ask my co-mods at SR, but I think we'd not be opposed to this – two of us already indicated that here, just Nicolas is missing :D

Comment: @Izzy I agree... some of the Q would take a bit of work to fit on SR.  I'm hoping that we could come up with a quick way to say "Hi... now that you're question is on SR, please read the SR guidelines and edit as needed".  Worse comes to worse, if the experiment fails, we can always remove the new option from Android SE.  I'm hoping for 3 outcomes: (1) fewer OT questions on Android SE, (2) more OT questions on SR SE, (3) more general awareness of SR SE (we don't get as many Android app requests as one might expect, given the popularity of Android).

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket (1) is unlikely to happen by this. As for the quality: it needs 5 user-votes to get a migration through – until then a mod should have had a chance to "hammer it the other way" (i.e. close it as OT with a hint to re-ask, pointing to above link), so I consider the risk of low-QQs being migrated rather low. Should we be wrong, it can be reverted. (3) will be achieved for users with close privileges. // PS: As Firelord pointed out, we can edit "custom close reasons" but I couldn't find a link for migration targets either. Nor one to contact CM, by the way.

Comment: The current SOP is to [tag the question with 'status-review'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348642/241919). However, we still need to [provide strong arguments as answers that the migration path worths](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261196/241919) //cc: @Izzy

Comment: @AndrewT. "2. That topic is asked about daily on the former site." Is it? Weekly we could say, but daily I don't think. So would we even stand a chance? We could try, though – it's about adding 1 site to the migration path, and SR is the one we encounter most frequently. Then quite a gap before another one "occasionally" shows up. Guess it's a 50:50 chance.

Comment: @Izzy well, it certainly worths trying. We don't have much stat about this migration path because we've been closing them aggressively in the first place  (same for HardwareRecs.SE)

Comment: Glad this finally hit the system. Seems there are other similar questions here on meta, including mine created in early 2014. Maybe they could be addressed (or add [duplicate] flags to redirect here).

Comment: @wbogacz I have closed your question as a duplicate of this one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**SoftwareRecs.SE has been added to the official migration path of Android.SE.**

[image]